# Video attachment from gallery not working in UIWebview in iOS 10.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, attachment

When trying to attach the video file in an email attachment, the file is not getting attached. Tested on iOS 10.2, 11.0 versions and it's working fine, then tested on iOS 10.3.2 and it's not attaching the video.  When seeing the device logs, I found this error message:

> : SandboxViolation: my_app deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0495.MOV

But my application is having all the permissions and I'm still not able to attach the videos.

Comment: Maybe that version has specific, now deprecated calls to get access outside of the sandbox it is in? In the BSD kernel to my knowledge, all programs are essentially users with limited rights running in their own little environment so they can't influence the system, and without the right permission setting for that version, it won't allow you to do this.

Comment: @G_V may be the issue is OS specific, Tried in safari with the same email client in my case Gmail working as expected. The video is getting attached perfectly.